# PHP Socket_recvfrom

Tags: php, sockets

Ok so im editing some code that was already written

But i seem to be struggling, I did try a search on here, but could not find what i was looking for.

Anyway.

```
    $recv = socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 2036, 0, $ip, $port);
    if($recv == false){

        echo "failed to recv ".socket_last_error()."<br>\n";
        return '';

    } else {

        echo "<br>BUF Recieved: ".$recv." bytes\n\n";
        echo"<br><br>";
        echo $buf . "\n";
    }
```

Now my issue is that I only seem to be able to receive 1036 bytes of information, it randomly cuts off only displaying part of what it should. As you can see I have tried increasing where it says 2036, I even increased this to 65k and still nothing.

Maybe I need some kind of delay so it has chance to retreive the information?

heres what i get

BUF Recieved: 1036 bytes

then a list of the players, but not the whole player list. it randomly cuts off after the 1036 bytes.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to recive multiple times from the socket, maybe the sending server splits the message.

Comment: Don't know why that idea didnt pop into my head, Set myself up a while loop to repeatedly retrieve until it finishes. Thanks man, your a life saver